# Unable to remove URL from Azure App Registrations

Tags: azure, azure-cli, azure-app-registration

I'm trying to remove a specific URL from Azure App Registrations. I tried the below command.

```
az ad app update --id <app-id> --remove web-redirect-uris 0
```

I used '0' (Index) as it doesn't allow us to delete the URL value. But it gives below error.

```
Couldn't find 'web' in 'web.redirect'. Available options: []
```

UPDATED

```
az rest \
          --method PATCH \
          --uri "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/applications/<object-id>" \
          --headers 'Content-Type=application/json' \
          --body “{web:{redirectUris: https://URL1}}”

unrecognized arguments: https://URL1}}”
```

**New**

```
az rest \
  --method "delete" \
  --uri "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/applications/<object-id>" \
  --headers "{'Content-Type': 'application/json'}" \
  --body "{'web': 'redirectUris': [ 'https://URL1' ] }"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per august 2022, it is not supported anymore (due to MS Graph Migration).

From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/microsoft-graph-migration#known-issues):

> Generic update arguments `--add`, `--set` and `--remove` currently don't work. You may use `az rest` to directly call Microsoft Graph API for non-supported properties.

You can track the github issue here: [Azure CLI cannot set values on nested properties](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/23443).

so in your case something like that should work

```
az rest \
  --method "patch" \
  --uri "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/applications/<object-id>" \
  --headers "{'Content-Type': 'application/json'}" \
  --body "{'web': 'redirectUris': [ 'https://URL1' ] }"
```

Comment: Using the az rest command can we remove a URL from App Registrations?

Comment: I used the above REST command, but it gives an error

Comment: using az rest, you could always use a `PUT` and only update what you need.

Comment: I used PUT but it gives the same error, any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: redirectUris should be an array.

Comment: --body “{"web":{"redirectUris": ["https:// URL1"]}}”

Comment: It says no matches found: [https://URL1]}}”

Comment: But in my case the method should be 'DELETE'?

Comment: I want to delete the URL from App Registration, so the method should be DELETE?

Comment: delete would delete the app registration

Comment: Well, my intention is to only delete/ remove a specific URL.

Comment: I have added the azure rest command under NEW section. So that would only delete the URL (https://URL1) from App Registration? It wont delete the App Registration know?

Comment: did you try the command from my asnwer ? it will delete anything except `https://URL1`.

Comment: Well, I want to delete https:// URL1

Comment: Let's say there are 3 URLs (URL1, URL2, URL3). I want to delete only URL1. I know if I execute your command with only URL2 and URL3 will delete the URL1. But isn't there any other way to specifically delete a URL?

Comment: you could always get the existings redirectUris and delte the one you want from the array before updating the app